# Skip offset in C struct

Tags: c, linux, gcc, data-structures, struct

When I write a struct I want that specific value will be into specific offset

```
struct test

{
   int dummy1[100];//dummy
   int id_s ;
   int dummy2[5];//dummy
   int id_t;

}
```

What I want from this struct only 2 members : `id_s` and `id_t` , and I want that `id_s` will be in offset of 400 (100 * 4) and `id_t` will be in offset of (100 * 4 +4 + 5*4)

Is there any simple way to do that instead put some dummy fields ?

Comment: if you just want to read 2 int values like that then why use a huge struct just for this? It takes more time to copy the struct then locating those 2 fields

Comment: No, there is no other way. Why do you want to do this? This sounds like a very strange requirement. Is this an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: @phuclv I would assume that the struct will never be used to define a variable but only to access memory from some buffer. Using a pointer to such a struct to overlay another memory area does not cause any performance issues.

Comment: If you want to get some fields from a large buffer with a layout defined by some protocol or another application, you could just write some `READ`/`WRITE` macros that take the base address and add the offset before accessing the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any simple way to do that instead put some dummy fields ?

As a general portable solution: No

The C standard does not require the type `int` to be 4 bytes. Further, the C standard allows for padding in structs so that may also change layout. So you can't just write a struct like yours and rely on the offsets being what you want on **all** systems.

But for most systems it will work as you expect.

I would however do two changes.

1. Use `char` for dummies.

Like:

```
struct test
{
   char dummy1[400];//dummy
   int id_s ;
   char dummy2[20];//dummy
   int id_t;

};
```

2. Make the struct packed.

Like:

```
struct test
{
   char dummy1[400];//dummy
   int id_s ;
   char dummy2[20];//dummy
   int id_t;

} __attribute__((__packed__));
```

As you can't be 100% sure that it work, I would also add asserts (static) that veirifies that the layout is as expected.

Like:

```
_Static_assert(offsetof(struct test, id_s) == 400, "Illegal offset for id_s in struct test");
_Static_assert(offsetof(struct test, id_t) == 424, "Illegal offset for id_t in struct test");
```

To take the integer size in to account and still get the offsets 400 and 424, you could do:

```
struct test
{
   char dummy1[400];//dummy
   int id_s ;
   char dummy2[24 - sizeof(int)];//dummy
   int id_t;

} __attribute__((__packed__));
```

Comment: Why do I need to use `__attribute__((__packed__)` please ?

Comment: @user13145920 It's because the compiler per default is allowed to insert padding between struct members. Padding is kind of like "extra dummies without name" and with a compiler decided  size. If you want fixed offsets, you don't want padding. You turn that of by saying the struct must be packed. Then the compiler is not allowed to add "extra dummies"

Comment: @user13145920 If you told what you are going to use that struct for, we may be able to give you a better solution....

Comment: Why don't you use standard types like `int32_t` to make it a bit more portable?

Comment: @thebusybee Because OP explicit asked for `int`. Had OP asked for a 32 bit integer type, I would have used fixed width. A "problem" with the question is that OP didn't give any information about the usage. Therefore we can't suggest better alternatives.

Comment: The question includes the size of the integers. ;-) I was just curious.

Comment: @thebusybee I don't see any `sizeof(int)` in the question. I just see the number `4`. On most systems `int32_t` will be the same as `int` but we can't be sure. In any case: If they are the same it doesn't matter which is used. In they differ, OP is in trouble...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any simple way to do that instead put some dummy fields ?

Write your own accessors.

> What I want from this struct only 2 members : id_s and id_t , and I want that id_s will be in offset of 400 (100 * 4) and id_t will be in offset of (100 * 4 +4 + 5*4)

Place them at specific byte-offsets yourself:

```
#define TEST_ID_S_OFFSET  (100*4)
// 100*4 +4 ? Why +4?
#define TEST_ID_T_OFFSET  (TEST_ID_S_OFFSET + sizeof(int) + 5*4)
struct test {
   char data[TEST_ID_T_OFFSET + sizeof(int)];
};

int test_get_id_s(struct test *t) {
      int ret;
      memcpy(&ret, &t->data[TEST_ID_S_OFFSET], sizeof(ret));
      return ret;
}
void test_set_id_s(struct test *t, int val) {
      memcpy(&t->data[TEST_ID_S_OFFSET], &val, sizeof(val));
}
int test_get_id_t(struct test *t) {
      int ret;
      memcpy(&ret, &t->data[TEST_ID_T_OFFSET], sizeof(ret));
      return ret;
}
void test_set_id_s(struct test *t, int val) {
      memcpy(&t->data[TEST_ID_T_OFFSET], &val, sizeof(val));
}
```